# Troubleshoot Client disconnected due to reason : 15

Tags: wireless

I have a Rasperry Pi connected to my house via Wifi and all worked well.
Now I am trying to install the server in a friend's house, but it seems to be stuck in a loop.
Especialy I see :

```
Client disconnected due to reason : 15.
```

How can I try to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't give a lot of information in this question.  For example, what OS are you using? What hardware are you using?  What was your setup process?  All of this is important to solving the problem effectively, so please edit them into the question.

Comment: HI sybOrg, thanks for your answer.
I just wanted to know what could be the causes of this error message from Protocol. It is not OS dependent as it is a protocol. I found my answer : bad password (mistake between French/English keyboard). So one possible mistake leading to this error code is : invalid password. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you found the solution to your own answer, you should write up an answer so that you can get some reputation for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the classic cause leading to this behaviour is when the password provided is wrong.

See the file :

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Error code list : [a page with a list of error codes](http://www.aboutcher.co.uk/2012/07/linux-wifi-deauthenticated-reason-codes/)